# how can i make an image point towards the mouse in python

Tags: python

so I am making a game where the movement involves the player always moving towards the mouse. unfortunately, I have no idea how to do either of these things, but the most important one right now is rotating the image towards the mouse. please help?

Comment: You need to bring the code with what you have already tried so that we can help you, ask for a complete code so there is no way to help, you will only receive negative votes, it is better to delete the question and create a new one with the code and your failed attempts .

Comment: i have not done any code. as i have stated, i have no idea where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. turns out, i need to use some trig.

```
self.x += Pl_NPC.speed * cos(self.angle * pi / 180)
self.y -= Pl_NPC.speed * sin(self.angle * pi / 180)
```

for the movement

```
self.mouseposx, self.mouseposy = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
rel_x, rel_y = mouse_x - self.x, mouse_y - self.y-43
angle = (180 / pi) * -atan2(rel_y, rel_x)
self.img = pygame.transform.rotate(self.orgimg, int(angle) + -90)
self.rect = self.img.get_rect(center=self.pos)
self.angle = int(angle)
```

for the rotation (this found on the internet)